# drop postgreSQL table with Quotation Marks in name using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, character-encoding, psycopg2

I have a table in a schema.

```
my_schema.my_table
```

In the same schema, I also have a table named the same but with quotation marks

```
my_schema."my_table"
```

How can I drop `my_schema."my_table"` using psycopg2?
(without risking to drop `my_schema.my_table`)

I have tried:

```
postgresConnection = psycopg2.connect(...)
from psycopg2 import sql 

cursor                = postgresConnection.cursor()
name_Table            = 'my_schema."my_table"'
cursor                = postgresConnection.cursor()
dropTableStmt   = "drop TABLE %s;"%name_Table;
cursor.execute(dropTableStmt)
postgresConnection.commit()
cursor.close();
```

But I get

```
SyntaxError: zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: drop TABLE my_schema.""my_table"";
```

I have also tried:

```
from psycopg2 import sql 

cursor                = postgresConnection.cursor()
name_Table            = 'my_schema.""my_table""'
cur = postgresConnection.cursor()
cur.execute(sql.SQL("DROP table {table}").format(table=sql.Identifier(name_Table)))
postgresConnection.commit()
cursor.close();
```

But then I get:

```
UndefinedTable: table "my_schema.""my_table""" does not exist
```

Comment: `my_table` is the same as "my_table" if they are in the same schema. In `psql` do `\dt my_schema.*` to confirm.

Comment: As to your error in the `sql.SQL` see [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) `class psycopg2.sql.Identifier` and `sql.Identifier("schema", "table")`.

Comment: they were different tables for some reason. your second comment solved, could you make it an answer?

Comment: So `my_schema.my_table` still exists? If so there must be some sort of hidden character in the name. What happens if you do `select * from pg_class where relname = 'my_table';`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To escape double quotes in an object name, double the double quotes:

```
DROP TABLE my_schema."""my_table""";
```